# Read a binary file with Fortran - if no input list provided, how many bytes does Fortran skip?

Tags: python, fortran, binaryfiles

I'm trying to understand some Fortran code. At one point there is line where it reads a binary file without specifying any input list, just the file itself and a statement label for reaching the end of the file:

```
open (unit=unitname,file='name.ext',form='unformatted',status='old',iostat=ios)
...
read (myFile,end=902)
```

I read the file with some Python code and with some debugging, I realized that the Fortran code skips exactly 2484 bytes (yes, I counted!) with this `read` command. I don't know if there is a special reason for this. If I'm not mistaken, a `read` command in Fortran would simply read the whole line without any input list, but as this is a binary file, I wonder what happens then. Where does this 2484 magic number come from? What happens when you read a binary file without specifing an input list in Fortran?

Comment: How is the file connected, ie., what `open` statement is there?  It's almost certainly an unformatted sequential access file, and the record is of length around that number.

Comment: yes, indeed it is unformatted: open (unit=unitname,file='name.ext',form='unformatted',status='old',iostat=ios)
Does the data follow the record number?

Comment: The record length is embedded in the file, see here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15071797/1004168

Comment: As explained already, Fortran is skipping a single record.  Most likely, the record has 2476 data bytes from whatever data items were written by the program that created it and 8 additional bytes, 4 pre and 4 post, specifying the length.  e.g., see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190092/how-do-i-read-fortran-binary-file-in-c   You can check the value in the first 4 and last 4 bytes to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

For a file connected for sequential access, a `read` statement with no input items advances the position of the file by a record.

For formatted input, as you note in the question, such a read would skip a line: in a file for this, a record is generally a line.

The same idea holds for unformatted input, from what you're calling a binary file.  What is meant by a record here is a little beyond the scope of this answer perhaps (and there are lots of nuances around this), but the crucial thing to note is that there is still a well-defined notion of a record's size.

And to fully justify the statement, your file is indeed connected for unformatted transfer (and is compatible with that `read` statement):

```
open (unit=unitname,file='name.ext',form='unformatted',status='old',iostat=ios)
```

Without an `access=` specifier to the contrary in that `open` the mode is sequential.