# Is it easy to ready in Python a very simple list of 64 bit floating point numbers writen as UNFORMATTED with Gfortran?

Tags: python, binary, binaryfiles, gfortran

I wrote this very simple list of 5 numbers with the following code, compiled with gfortran on a 64 bit Linux machine:

```
integer, parameter :: binary64  = selected_real_kind(15, 307)
real(kind=binary64) :: zero, one, pi
zero = 0.0_binary64
one  = 1.0_binary64
pi   = 3.141592653589793238_binary64
open(unit=10, file="test", action="write", status="new", form="unformatted")
write(unit=10) zero
write(unit=10) one
write(unit=10) pi
write(unit=10) zero
write(unit=10) one
close(unit=10)
```

They I can read the file in hexadecimal with:

```
xxd short.test.file_binary64
```

That is the output:

```
0000000: 0800 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0800 0000  ................
0000010: 0800 0000 0000 0000 0000 f03f 0800 0000  ...........?....
0000020: 0800 0000 182d 4454 fb21 0940 0800 0000  .....-DT.!.@....
0000030: 0800 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0800 0000  ................
0000040: 0800 0000 0000 0000 0000 f03f 0800 0000  ...........?....
```

So each register has a number: 0, 10, 20, 30, 40. I am not sure what part of the other things correspond to 0,1, pi, 1, 1 and what is the meaning of the 0800 000, and I don't know what the other thing is (a failed representation in ascii?)

And if I do a binary read:

```
xxd -b short.test.file_binary64
```

The output is even more cryptic:

```
0000000: 00001000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......
0000006: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......
000000c: 00001000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001000 00000000  ......
0000012: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......
0000018: 00000000 00000000 11110000 00111111 00001000 00000000  ...?..
000001e: 00000000 00000000 00001000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......
0000024: 00011000 00101101 01000100 01010100 11111011 00100001  .-DT.!
000002a: 00001001 01000000 00001000 00000000 00000000 00000000  .@....
0000030: 00001000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......
0000036: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......
000003c: 00001000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001000 00000000  ......
0000042: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......
0000048: 00000000 00000000 11110000 00111111 00001000 00000000  ...?..
000004e: 00000000 00000000
```

I need to read this data in Python. Hence my three questions, and I believe the first one is very simple:

1. Is this issue something straightforward and easy and there is just some piece of information I need to learn after doing a reasonable amount of research?
2. This is a rather complicated issue because binary files are cpu and compiler dependent blablabla and I might spend a week doing research around internet and still not being able to sort it out?
3. How can I read the data in Python?

Comment: There are lots of related questions which cover various details.  Two examples: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37063864); [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8131204).  Looking instead at simply Fortran aspects will say much, but the same issues will appear with C, C++, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The format is 32bit integer length, 64bit double value, 32bit integer length for each dataset.

You can decode with `struct`, eg. the third dataset

```
import struct
data = b'\x08\x00\x00\x00\x18-DT\xfb!\t@\x08\x00\x00\x00'
l1, value, l2 = struct.unpack("<idi", data)
# (8, 3.141592653589793, 8)
```

So you need to read your file in blocks of 16 bytes:

```
with open("short.test.file_binary64", "rb") as binary:
    while True:
        data = binary.read(16)
        if not data:
            break
        l1, value, l2 = struct.unpack("<idi", data)
        print(value)
```

Comment: The data in your answer doesn't seem to match the data in the question. Also, did you mean 32-bit lengths? And do you have any source you can cite for this format, or are you just guessing based on what seems plausible?

Comment: @user2357112: mistake due to automatic padding of a 64bit system; answer corrected.

Comment: Awesome! Could you explain the first line? (data = b'\x08\x00\x00\x00\x18-DT\xfb!\t@\x08\x00\x00\x00'). My python is quite poor for the moment.

Comment: @Mephiso: for testing purpose, this is the contents of the third line of your binary file.

Comment: How can I read the original file? pylab.loadtxt does not like the binary data.

Comment: @Mephisto: see my post

Comment: @Daniel, We're almost there, but it says: TypeError: an integer is required

Comment: @Mephisto: in which line the TypeError occurs?

Comment: @Daniel open("short.test.file_binary64", "rb")

Comment: @ Could you post the exact contents of a file that works for you?